# Bootstrap Navbar Center Text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text, center, navbar

I have recently implemented a collapse bootstrap navbar to my website. However I have an issue with it when it is in its full form. The text is aligned to the left of the navbar and despite much CSS config, and browsing of stackoverflow none of the changes I have tried have been successful at all.
I am trying to change the navbar so that the text/links within it are centralized.

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>


        </div><!-- end navbar-header -->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
                    <li><a href="#home">Days Out</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Ghosts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Beasts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Gifts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end collapse -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You just need to change the `float` behavior of the navbar, try adding this styles:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  text-align:center;
}
.navbar-nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

#### [BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/xQ92RvTUex)

Comment: I have included a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b8yjgk6a/ as you can see it is only when the screen is of a large size than the navbar itself, causing it to place the text in the left, and stretch the navbar across the container. Is there a way I can get it center the text when the screen is larger? I have tried editing your provided code within the media for a large screen but to no avail

Comment: @AdamFenwick In your fiddle doesn't work since the css of bootstrap is overriding all the others since the way jsfiddle works allows that.... but it will work if you work with the right specificity

Comment: How would I change it so that it overrides bootstrap? As so far I have implemented your code above, but once it gets to a specific size (My monitor) the navbar continues to fill the container, however the text remains aligned to the left

Comment: @AdamFenwick try putting !important after text-align:center;

Comment: @RachelGallen When Collapsed the Text appears Centered, however it does not when in full navbar

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries. It's the heart and soul of Bootstrap.

Since BS3's default breakpoint for collapsing the nav is at 767px. Why not define how you want it to behave above and below that point.

One possible solution as such would be...

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
 .navbar-collapse {
    text-align:center;
    }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
 .navbar-collapse {
    text-align:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using media queries for large screens, but the text still will not center when the nav is not collapsed. The website is live at adamfenwickweb.co.uk if that makes it easier to see the issue in action